# get value of one column by another column in csv file python

Tags: python

I have my csv file like this:

```
ID        Value      Amount 
----      -------    -------
A           3          2
A           4          4
B           3          6
C           5          5
A           3          2
B           10         1
```

I want sum of column "Value" or "Amount" by the column "ID". I want the output that for 'A' it should give me sum of all values which is related to A means [3+4+3].

My Code:

```
import csv
file = open(datafile.csv)
rows=csv.DictReader(file)
summ=0.0
count=0
for r in rows:
  summ=summ+int(r['Value'])
  count=count+1
print "Mean for column Value is: ",(summ/count)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` of `list` to group the data by the ID column. Then use `sum()` to produce the totals.

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('datafile.csv') as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    next(f)    # skip first header line
    next(f)    # skip second header line
    for line in f:
        id_, value, amount = line.split()
        d[id_].append((int(value), int(amount)))

# sum and average of column Value by ID
for id_ in d:
    total = sum(t[0] for t in d[id_])
    average = total / float(len(d[id_]))
    print('{}: sum = {}, avg = {:.2f}'.format(id_, total, average))
```

Output for your input data:

```
A: sum = 10, avg = 3.33
C: sum = 5, avg = 5.00
B: sum = 13, avg = 6.50
```

---

It can also be done with a standard Python dictionary. The solution is very similar:

```
with open('datafile.csv') as f:
    d = {}
    next(f)    # skip first header line
    next(f)    # skip second header line
    for line in f:
        id_, value, amount = line.split()
        d[id_] = d.get(id_, []) + [(int(value), int(amount))]

# sum and average of column Value by ID
for id_ in d:
    total = sum(t[0] for t in d[id_])
    average = total / float(len(d[id_]))
    print('{}: sum = {}, avg = {:.2f}'.format(id_, total, average))
```

Comment: I don't want to use collection.

Comment: @mohammadshahbazKhan: really? Why not?

Comment: I am clearing my basic skills on python. I am trying to find out the ways without using collection.

Comment: Does a dictionary count as a "collection"? What about a list? It's pretty difficult to do this without some kind of collection like data structure.

Comment: you can use dictionary or List.

Comment: A `defaultdict` _is_ a dictionary, so you could argue that the problem is solved. If you want to use a standard dictionary the solution is very similar. I have updated my answer.